# How to format numbers as percentage values but to still be able to treat ir numercially?

Tags: r, format, percentage, numeric

I want to know if it's possible to display values on a table as percentages but still be able to do arithmetic operations with them.

I have tried using `percent()` from `scales` package, but it seems like it transforms the values from numeric to character. I have tried to convert them back using `as.numeric()`, but it will not work either.

Any solutions? Thank you.

Comment: As I have explained, I've tried using the solution provided there.

Comment: Once you `format`ted it become to `character` class.  If the aim is to identity the variable, then why not store is it with a variable name that include percent i.e `yourvar_percent <- values`  or another way is to create a `named` vector or `key/value` list where the names/keys would be the formatted percent sign pasted

Comment: `library(units); set_units(seq(0, 100, 25), make_unit('%'))`

Comment: As @akrun said, you will need to save it to a separate variable. Or perhaps develop your own class which will print percentage but still be numeric in the background.

Answer (score 6):

One very hacky way to do this would be as follows

```
x <- runif(10)
class(x) <- "percent"
print.percent <- function(x) print(scales::percent(as.numeric(x)))
```

This is probably useful for quick analyses or short scripts but I wouldn't put this into any kind of package or shared code.

Comment: There is nothing hacky about this. Add a method for format and you are good to go. Many people have S3 classes in packages.

Comment: I say it's hacky because to treat it numerically puts a lot of faith in implicit conversions from R. It will also not work as expected if used in a paste expression.

Comment: I don't understand. An object can have more than one class. If you write a constructor function that ensures that the returned object has class "numeric" there is no conversion necessary.

Comment: Well this solution is surprisingly robust, but also not fully predictable. For example you can take the `log(x)` and it will print with percent format but `mean(x)` will not.

Comment: mean is an S3 generic. The default method strips attributes, but you can write your own method.